# Post excerpt just on front page

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Twenty Fifteen to create my custom WP theme.

On the front page I would like to have my posts showing the excerpt of them.
When on the content.php I change the_content for the_excerpt everything works well on the home page, but on the post page there's no text anymore, but again, just the excerpt.

How can I define to show the excerpt just on the front page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside content.php, you can wrap the two in an if statement to check if the page is the front page.

```
if(is_front_page()){
    the_excerpt();
} else {
    the_content();
}
```

Comment: That was so fast, and so accurate!
Thank you @frederikvdbe!

Comment: Glad I could help!